# How to get "Date added to Heath" from HealthKit

Tags: swift, healthkit

I want to get this value to determine which will be removed when data overlaps.
Is there any way to get this value from HealthKit?

Thanks.
[This image shows the date added from Health App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76cIk.png)

I tried all [Queries](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/reading_data_from_healthkit#2962446) but I got no value containing the date added.

**Update:** we can get the Date added by using `HKSample`.value(forKey: "creationTimestamp") where `HKSample` is the sample data we got when query.

Comment: It's probably better to use the start and end date. WasUserEntered will only distinguish been device generated vs user entered values.

Comment: The date record was added is what I want, not `WasUserEntered`